# Logging Summary screen with InstallAnywhere

Tags: logging, summary, installanywhere

I am using console based installer of InstallAnywhere 2010 and want to log all the content of the summary screen.

Any idea, how o achieve that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find any way to Log the summary screen.

There is way to debug all the details like variable, installation tree structure etc. by using IA control "Debug Information". But U can log the Summary Screen.

All I did to achieve this, is used CustomCosoleAction class to generate Summary, rather than using IA "Summary Screen".

:)